# Using Duende Identity Server behind a Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, blazor, microservices

**Overview**

I have a micro-service solution that includes a Blazor application, web API services, and Duende Identity Server. Also, I used Nginx as a reverse proxy for access to services. When I configure Blazor App to use Duende for authentication directly, it works correctly, but when I want to add Nginx between them, it does not work. I followed IdentityServer/IdentityServer4#1623 (comment) to solve this issue, but I couldn't succeed. Below, I describe the services configuration and what I am doing so far :

**Nginx**

The Nginx.conf has been configured as follows:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
     worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
     include       mime.types;
     default_type  application/octet-stream;
     log_format  main  '[$time_local]-status :[$status] - $remote_addr - $host - UriAddr: [$request_uri] - XFF : ["$http_x_forwarded_for"] '
                  '- BodyByteSent : [$body_bytes_sent] "$http_referer" '
                  '"$request"'; #"$http_user_agent"
     access_log  logs/access.log  main;
     sendfile        on; 
     keepalive_timeout  300;   
     include nginx_http.conf;  
}
```

And nginx_http.conf has been configured as follows:

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    server_tokens off;

    gzip on;
    gzip_buffers      16 8k;
    gzip_comp_level   4;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_min_length   1280;
    gzip_types        *;
    gzip_vary         on;    
    gzip_disable msie6;
    charset UTF-8;
    include nginx_access_control.conf;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        #proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;

        proxy_pass         https://127.0.0.1:5001/;
    }
location /Identity/ {
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:12000/;
    }

}
```

**Duende Identity Service**

this service runs on https://localhost:12001/ and HTTP://localhost:12000/ with dotnet 6
The Identity Server Configure is as follows:

```
 builder.Services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.IssuerUri = "http://localhost/Identity/";
})
 .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
.AddInMemoryClients(new List<Client>
{
    new Client
    {
        ClientName = "Web User",
        ClientId = "web",/*"D2B8B5EC-9766-40B9-9D95-077B54245E6E",*/
        ClientSecrets= {new Secret("123456".Sha256())},
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
        // RedirectUris={"https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc"},
        RedirectUris={"http://localhost/signin-oidc"},
        PostLogoutRedirectUris={ "http://localhost/signout-callback-oidc" },
        AllowedScopes=
        {
            "openid",
            "profile"
        }
    }
}).AddInMemoryIdentityResources(new List<IdentityResource>
{
    new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
    new IdentityResources.Profile(),
})
.AddInMemoryApiScopes(new List<ApiScope>
{
    new ApiScope("Management.fullaccess")
})
.AddInMemoryApiResources(new List<ApiResource>
{
    new ApiResource("Management","Management Service")
    {
        Scopes = { "Management.fullaccess" }      
    }
})
.AddAspNetIdentity<User>();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

**Blazor App**

This service runs on https://localhost:5001/ and HTTP://localhost:5000/ with dotnet 5
The Startup Configuration is as follows:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var blazorSevice = services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });
        if (environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            blazorSevice.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        }
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor(o => o.DetailedErrors = true);
        services.AddAuthentication(p =>
            {
                p.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                p.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.Authority = "http://localhost/Identity";//"http://localhost:12000";
                options.MetadataAddress = "http://localhost/Identity/.well-known/openid-configuration";
                options.ClientId = "web";
                options.ClientSecret = "123456";
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                
            });

        services.AddTelerikBlazor();
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseForwardedHeaders();

        app.Use(async (httpcontext, next) =>
        {
            await next();
            string location = httpcontext.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Location];

            if ((httpcontext.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status302Found
                || httpcontext.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect)
                && location != "https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc"
                && location != "https://localhost:5001/")
            {
                location = location.Replace("https","http")
                    .Replace("://localhost:5001/", "://localhost/Identity/");
                httpcontext.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Location] = location;
            }
            if (httpcontext.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status302Found
                || httpcontext.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect)
            {
                if (location != "https://localhost:5001/" 
                    && location != "https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc" 
                    && !location.Contains("://localhost/Identity/"))
                {
                    location = location.Replace("%3A5001", "")
                        .Replace("://localhost/", "://localhost/Identity/")
                        .Replace("://localhost:12001/", "://localhost/Identity/");
                    httpcontext.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Location] = location;
                }
            }
        });
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub(option =>
                option.Transports = HttpTransportType.LongPolling);
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

In the above code, I try to change the HTTP response location with middleware to redirect the requests belonging to Duende Identity Server, but I think it's not a common approach!
With all configurations that showed above, now, when I run the blazor app, it redirects to the login page in the Duende service, but when I click the login button, it redirects to /signin-oidc route and shows the error:

[image]

It seems that after redirecting to /signin-oidc, the blazor app tries to get a token from /connect/token in the Duende service, and it returns an error.
I searched for similar solutions, but I couldn't find any things! Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem most like lies in the missing x-forwarded-for header. You need to use these headers to tell duende about the fact that you have a reverse proxy.

You can add the headers by adding the following middleware at the start of the pipeline:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues for almost 6 months with nginx and duende before I figured this out. Since I didn't see it in your config I assumed it may help you at some point.

So duende sends the payload back to the calling server via headers, and they are quite large compared to what Nginx expects for normal headers. This caused the requests to fail. The solution was to expand the header size as such

```
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
```

Since I use nginx proxy manager, to add this to the configuration we need to go into the config files and under

```
nginx/custom/http_top.conf
```

Depending on your nginx flavor the target may vary.